# не срабатывает скрипт на клик по кнопке

Tags: javascript, jquery

При клике на процессор открывается модальное окно, и если кликать по кнопке в модальном окне, то этот скрипт не срабатывает.

```
function action_but(code, ttl, pid, total_cost){
    $("#new_window .head p").html(ttl);
    $.post("assets/get.php", { act:pid, сid:code, cost:total_cost })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#new_window #select_complect").html(data);
    });
    $("#new_window").removeClass('hidden');
}

$(".constructor .result_category .add").click(function(){
    var total_cost = $('.sidebar .sbor .price span').text();
    var code = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var ttl = $(this).closest(".data_footer").find("h2").text();
    var pid = $(this).closest(".ln").find("input[type=hidden]").val();
    if (total_cost === "") total_cost = "null";
    if (pid === "") pid = "null";
    action_but(code, ttl, pid, total_cost);
    return false;
});

$("#new_window #select_complect .element .choise").click(function(){
   var total_cost_all = $('.sidebar .sbor .price span').text();
    var pid_d = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var parent_d = $(this).attr("data-parent");
    alert(total_cost_all);
    alert(pid_d);
    alert(parent_d);
    return false;
 });
```

http://technogik.ru/kalkulyator-sborki

Comment: Это модальное окно генерируется средствами JS после нажатия на процессор?

Comment: удаляет класс hidden, исправил вопрос, гляньте, там весь код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Корректный код:

```
$('#select_complect').on("click", ".choise", function() {
   var total_cost_all = $('.sidebar .sbor .price span').text();
    var pid_d = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var parent_d = $(this).attr("data-parent");
    alert(total_cost_all);
    alert(pid_d);
    alert(parent_d);
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: спасибо , выручили